# Parsing chemical formulas using regex expressions

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to do the following thing: given a single-column `pandas.Dataframe` (of chemical formulas) like

```
    formula
0   Hg0.7Cd0.3Te
1   CuBr
2   Lu
...
```

I would like to return a `pandas.Series` like

```
0         [(Hg, 0.7), (Cd, 0.3), (Te,1)]
1                [(Cu, 1), (Br, 1)]
2                [(Lu, 1), (P, 1)]
...
```

So this is the desired output.

I've already tried something with a regex expression:

```
counts = pd.Series(formulae.values.flatten()).str.findall(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", re.I)
```

but unfortunately my output is the following:

```
0         [(Hg, 0), (Cd, 0)]
1                         []
2                         []
3       [(Cu, 3), (SbSe, 4)]
```

so it's not recognizing in some cases different elements in the chemical formula.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to be improved:

1. The number pattern does not allow floating point numbers yet. Here, you can use `([0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?)` instead.
2. The number might not be present at all, so that needs to be indicated by a trailing `?`.
3. The elements all start with an uppercase letter, followed by zero or more (zero or one?) lower case letters. So the element name pattern would be `[A-Z][a-z]*`. That's important to distinguish different elements with no number in between, e.g. `'CuBr'` (so ignore-case wouldn't work here).

Putting it all together:

```py
from pprint import pprint
import re

formulae = ['Hg0.7Cd0.3Te', 'CuBr', 'Lu']

pattern = re.compile('([A-Z][a-z]*)([0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?)?')

pprint([pattern.findall(f) for f in formulae])
```

The prints the following:

```py
[[('Hg', '0.7'), ('Cd', '0.3'), ('Te', '')],
 [('Cu', ''), ('Br', '')],
 [('Lu', '')]]
```

As you can see, missing numbers are denoted by empty strings which you need to postprocess manually. For example:

```py
result = [pattern.findall(f) for f in formulae]
result = [[(e, float(n or 1)) for e, n in f] for f in result]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'formula':['Hg0.7Cd0.3Te', 'CuBr', 'Lu']})
df['counts'] = df['formula'].str.findall(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?')
df['counts'] = df['counts'].apply(lambda x: [(a,b) if b else (a,1) for a,b in x])
```

Output:

```
>>> df['counts']
0    [(Hg, 0.7), (Cd, 0.3), (Te, 1)]
1                 [(Cu, 1), (Br, 1)]
2                          [(Lu, 1)]
```

*Details*:

- `([A-Z][a-z]*)` - Group 1: an uppercase letter followed with zero or more lowercase letters
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?` - an optional group 2: one or more diits followed with an optional occurrence of a dot and one or more digits.

The `df['counts'].apply(lambda x: [(a,b) if b else (a,1) for a,b in x])` adds `1` as each tuple second item where it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Would use multiple replace to introduce separators, split using introduced separators, explode and then filter. Code below

```
repl2 =  lambda g: f'{str(g.group(1)) }<'
repl3 =  lambda g: f'{str(g.group(1)) }>'
df1 = (df1.assign(formula1=df1['formula'].str.replace('((?<=[A-Z])\w)', repl3, regex=True)#Introduce separator where alpha numeric follows a cap letter
                 .str.replace('(\d(?=[A-Z]))', repl2, regex=True))#Introduce separator where digits is followed by cap letter
.replace(regex={r'\>(?=0)': ',', '\>': ',1 '})#Replace the < and > introduced separators
      )

df1=df1.assign(formula1=df1['formula1'].str.split('\<|\s')).explode('formula1')#Explode dataframe

new=df1[df1['formula1'].str.contains('\w')]#filter those rows that have details



    formula      formula1
0  Hg0.7Cd0.3Te   Hg,0.7
0  Hg0.7Cd0.3Te   Cd,0.3
0  Hg0.7Cd0.3Te     Te,1
1          CuBr     Cu,1
1          CuBr     Br,1
2            Lu     Lu,1
```